# Android pie killing the background service

Tags: android, android-9.0-pie

There are few questions similar to this in the StackOverFlow but none of the solutions are working for me.

My app running a background service for location tracking. It's works fine every OS's except Android Pie. Android Pie killing the background service after a while (about 10 minutes).

- targetSdkVersion is 27 and still didn't update the API VERSION to 28.
- I have tested using HUAWEI NOVA 3i.

Service code is like below.

```
override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent?, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {
    return START_STICKY
}


override fun onCreate() {
    super.onCreate()
    startForeground(N_ID_ONGOING_RACE, notification)
}
```

Start the service like below.

```
fun startServiceEx(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
    try {
        context.startService(intent)
    } catch (e: IllegalStateException) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            context.startForegroundService(intent)
        } else {
            context.startService(intent)
        }
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciate.

Comment: How many Android 9.0 devices did you test on? If it is just the one Huawei device, what makes you think that the problem is Android 9.0 and not the device?

Comment: HUAWEI are bad for testing. AFAIK HUAWEI devices contain custom code that kills background services for battery saving. Therefore a lot of apps that rely on background services don't work properly on HUAWEI devices.

Comment: Actually I have tested using pocophone(Android 9.0) also.

Comment: Have you tried on emulator it will work on emulator, i faced similar condition  Huawie devices with Oreo and below are working fine, but on Pie and above its stopping my service